# Display the MAX record with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having, having-clause

I want to select the highest transaction amount and the corresponding Album Name to that amount.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT a.AlbumName, MAX(t.TransAmt) AS HighestSale
FROM TRANSACTIONS t 
JOIN COLLECTIONS c ON c.CollectionID = t.CollectionID
JOIN ALBUMS a ON a.AlbumID = c.AlbumID
GROUP BY a.AlbumName
```

I know I need a HAVING in there but I am unsure how to implement it.

This is what I get currently:

| AlbumName | HighestSale |
| --- | --- |
| Cassadaga | 10.00 |
| I Walk The Line | 13.00 |
| Sweet Revenge | 14.00 |
| The Tree of Forgiveness | 12.00 |

I only want to see the HighestSale (14.00) and then the AlbumName (Sweet Revenge)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `ORDER BY` and fetching one row.  In Standard SQL"

```
SELECT a.AlbumName, t.TransAmt AS HighestSale
FROM TRANSACTIONS t JOIN
     COLLECTIONS c
     ON c.CollectionID = t.CollectionID JOIN
     ALBUMS a
     ON a.AlbumID = c.AlbumID
ORDER BY t.TransAmt DESC
OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Some databases don't support the standard `FETCH` clause, so you might want `LIMIT` or `SELECT TOP (1)` or something else.

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to respond and say I was getting this: "Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement."  But I saw your update. SELECT TOP 1 is working. I am using MS SQL. Thanks again

Comment: @nathan, for MS SQL questions, you should add the <sql-server> tag also.

Comment: @jarlh oops okay thanks, new user here

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  my follow up question is what if I have two albums with the same price and they are max. I would want my query to show both.

Comment: @nathan SQL Server supports `TOP (1) WITH TIES`

Answer (score 0):

This can work also

```
SELECT a.AlbumName, MAX(t.TransAmt) AS 
HighestSale
FROM TRANSACTIONS t 
JOIN COLLECTIONS c ON c.CollectionID = 
t.CollectionID
JOIN ALBUMS a ON a.AlbumID = c.AlbumID
WHERE t.TransAmt = (SELECT MAX(TransAmt) 
FROM TRANSACTIONS) 
GROUP BY a.AlbumName
```